# Preserve single and double quotes inside bash script

Tags: python, bash, quotes, quote

I have to run a python script within bash, passing it a string which is stored in a variable... so inside bash I have:

```
python my_script.py $myvariable
```

myvariable is a string that can contain single/double quotes which I would preserve (since I make some splits in python script using that quotes). How could I preserve that quotes? Can I escape them somehow before passing to python? I know that I could surround myvariable too with single/double quotes, but I don't know the content of the string, so it would be faulty.

Comment: can you provide an example string that you would like to pass into the shell script?

Comment: The string could contain everything, since it's not created by me... just for example it could contain something like json... so: {"attribute1":v1,"attribute2":v2}. But this is just an example... as I said it could contain everything and I need to preserve quotes

Comment: Double quote the variable expansion. This works regardless of what the variable contains.

Comment: *python my_script.py "$(printf '%q' "$myvariable")"*

Comment: Use double-quotes: `python my_script.py "$myvariable"`. When the shell expands a variable in double-quotes, it doesn't do any parsing of the contents of the variable's value; it can contain quotes, escapes, etc, and they'll all just be included literally in the argument the program receives. (Actually, even if you *don't* double-quote it, quotes and escapes won't be parsed, but whitespace and filename wildcards will... which is almost never what you want. So you should pretty much always use double-quotes.)